# Is it possible to inject dynamic angular dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I have many widgets and component. After some time `admin` can add new component via `BOWER` and include in html file using `GRUNT`.

But how dynamic dependencies can be handle in angular.?

For example. I have following `module name` and `dependencies`

```
app = angular.module("sematree", ['ngRoute','ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap',
'adf', 'adf.structures.base', 'adf.widget.table']);
```

After some time i want to add  stackedColumnChart.js component in my application folder and want to add `'adf.widget.stackedColumnChart'` in my dependencies with opening my angular file.

Is it possibility that i can add dependencies using grunt.?
or It can be handle dynamic under same folder.?

Kindly give me idea.

Comment: you can create a global array of all dependencies and use the same for angular dependencies.
`var dependencies = ['ngRoute','ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap',
'adf', 'adf.structures.base', 'adf.widget.table'];
angular.module("sematree", dependencies);`

Comment: Have a look at this grut plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-extender. It might be what you're looking for..

Comment: Or this other post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209780/grunt-js-for-angular-js-dependency-injection-management

Comment: You should try https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad